# Import HTML snippet into other file

Tags: html

I was just working on a project today, and noticed I was copying and pasting a lot of content when it came to working on the nav section and I was wondering if there is a way to import an html snipped into a different html file so I don't have to keep copying and pasting. I was trying to solve this by using a "link" tag. It was setup like this:

index.html

```
<div> <link rel="import" href="nav.html"> </div>
```

nav.html

```
<a class="nav-link" href="reviews.html">Reviews</a>
<a class="nav-link" href="trending">Trending</a>
<a class="nav-link" href="contact">Contact</a>
<a class="nav-link" href="about">About</a>
<a class="nav-link" href="blog">Blog</a>
```

However, I noticed that this was not working, and I couldn't get the nav.html content to import into the index.html file. So instead of this, I had to keep copying and pasting.

Please let me know if you have a solution to this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe `iframe`? But I recommend a server-side solution instead.

Comment: What browser? Did you make sure that version of that browser supports HTML imports? Any errors in your JS console?

Comment: I would think iFrame would create a delay because it is not getting the code directly from another file uploaded to the website, but thanks for that suggestion!

Comment: I was using Google Chrome when trying this, and I do not have any JS on this page. I don't know much JS, mostly just HTML and CSS for now and some very basic PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have no server application to work with, you can do this with some simple AJAX - it would take an extra split-second for the navigation to appear, but it'll do the trick.

If you've got jQuery, it would look something like:

Each page would have:

```
<div id="navigation"></div>
```

You could have a shared javascript file with the following (assuming all pages are at the same level as the nav page):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "nav.html"
        ,dataType: "html"
    }).done(function(result) {
        jQuery("#navigation").html(result);
    });
});
```

Comment: Why not just `$( '#navigation' ).load( url )`.

Comment: @Danijel No real reason - personally I almost always the full `ajax` syntax, so I don't have to remember the various shortcuts or their signatures, but for something simple like this, yours is probably better.

Comment: I originally created this project as an upgrade from my old website one reason being to load faster, so even though it wouldn't be a noticeable difference really, I think I am going to avoid ajax as much as possible. But thanks for your help. I thought I would just be able to use a simple link tag in html but I guess its harder than I thought.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not quite clear... but you can call your Menu to be added to any page from your javascript file like this:

```
function AddTheMenu(){
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterEnd',
'<a class="nav-link" href="reviews.html">Reviews</a>'+
'<a class="nav-link" href="trending">Trending</a>'+
'<a class="nav-link" href="contact">Contact</a>'+
'<a class="nav-link" href="about">About</a>'+
'<a class="nav-link" href="blog">Blog</a>');
}
```

So every page that needs the Menu included just calls this:

```
AddTheMenu();
```

Comment: Oh I see. So are you saying to create a JS file with that function then use a link tag to import it into each html page and just call the function? This seems to be the easiest thing to do, thanks for the idea!

Comment: Exactly! I stuff my web-app pages with tons of elements that are common to all, in this way and it works like a charm.

Comment: Do you notice any lag on load while using this method or no, since its still within the website itself and not like ajax?

Comment: There shouldn’t be any lag, it’s just extra HTML that gets inserted at a time you specify with: 

 1. beforeBegin - Inserts the text immediately before the current element.
 2. afterBegin - Inserts the text immediately after the start of the current element.
 3. beforeEnd - Inserts the text immediately before the end of the current element.
 4. afterEnd - Inserts the text immediately after the current element.